# What is the point of passing in params to an abstract base class in this manner?

Tags: python, oop, abstract-base-class

I was trying to understand how the backtesting.py module is written and came across this code.

```
class Strategy(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """
    A trading strategy base class. Extend this class and
    override methods
    `backtesting.backtesting.Strategy.init` and
    `backtesting.backtesting.Strategy.next` to define
    your own strategy.
    """
    def __init__(self, broker, data, params):
        self._indicators = []
        self._broker: _Broker = broker
        self._data: _Data = data
        self._params = self._check_params(params)



    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Strategy ' + str(self) + '>'

    def __str__(self):
        params = ','.join(f'{i[0]}={i[1]}' for i in zip(self._params.keys(),
                                                        map(_as_str, self._params.values())))
        if params:
            params = '(' + params + ')'
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}{params}'

    def _check_params(self, params):
        for k, v in params.items():
            if not hasattr(self, k):
                raise AttributeError(
                    f"Strategy '{self.__class__.__name__}' is missing parameter '{k}'."
                    "Strategy class should define parameters as class variables before they "
                    "can be optimized or run with.")
            setattr(self, k, v)
        return params
```

From what I have understood it seems that the to instantiate an object of the strategy class we need three arguments `broker, data, params`  It seems that valid form of the `params` is supposed to be a dictionary with keys already being present as attributes. So does that mean `params = {broker : "blah", data: "blahblah"}` is the form that needs to be passed? WHat is the point of doing this in such a manner instead of directly passing the values to `data` and `broker`?

I tried to instantiate an object of the `Strategy` class using arbitrary dictionaries, just to understand what's going on.

This code `q = Strategy("nn", [],{"b":33, "a":44})` gives the following error:

`Strategy 'Strategy' is missing parameter 'b'.Strategy class should define parameters as class variables before they can be optimized or run with.`

However if I do this:

`q = Strategy("nn", [],{"_broker":33, "_data":44})`

The code runs without errors.

Whatpurpose does this serve?

Comment: Where does this code come from? This pattern is not very good

Comment: https://github.com/kernc/backtesting.py/blob/master/backtesting/backtesting.py

This is the source. It is quite a popular package though.

Comment: It looks like you *could* pass `_broker` or `_data` as dict keys in `params`, but that's certainly not the intended usage.  The concrete subclasses of this class will have one or more additional attributes defined, *those* are the keys that you would use in `params`.

Comment: The class inherits from `ABCMeta`, not `ABC`

Comment: @jasonharper why not define the additional attributes in the concrete subclasses directly? and what's the point of ```_check_params()``` that only adds attributes from keys in params if they are already present as attributes?

Comment: @TomMcLean yes sorry, I have edited the question to reflect that it inherits from ```ABCmeta```

Comment: It's also lazily checking if a *class* attribute exists by accessing the attribute via the *instance*. `_check_params` should probably be a class method that takes an instance as an explicit argument.

Comment: I can't say I'm really impressed with this approach - I guess the advantage is that each subclass doesn't have to define its own `__init__()`.  The check for the attribute already existing makes sure that you don't pass an option not known to the subclass.

Comment: But doesn't this mean we have to pass the same attribute twice once outside the ```params``` dictionary to make sure that it's already an attribute and once inside the ```params``` as a key?   Pardon me if this is a silly thing to get stuck on. 
Could you please provide an example where this roundabout way is helpful while creating concrete subclasses?

Comment: The subclass itself would define the attributes it expects, in the class body.  The user of the subclass would give those attributes values via `params`.